# Axis2 Web services

Tags: web-services

can anyone please explain **axis2** web service.
Is axis2 **SOAP** or **REST**??
Its very confusing. In REST it support multiple formats. 
But SOAP supports only a **XML** Formats.

Answer (score 2):

From apache axis2 [web site](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/)

> Apache Axis2™ is a Web Services / SOAP / WSDL engine, the successor to
>   the widely used Apache Axis SOAP stack.

By the way you can use [RESTful](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/rest-ws.html) with apache axis2.